# React caching strategy

Tags: reactjs, caching, react-redux

I'm new to Reactjs and using ASP.NET Core Web API app as back-end server. In one React component where I want to display a large amount of data in tables which I'm fetching from database through different API calls. The data have to be up-to-date to users which means that there is an interval of time to update the displaying data. And to enhance the performance, I would like to use cache.

I've seen the different caching strategies like localstorage and React Redux, but I'm confused which one may best fit my business logic. LocalStorage may not a good option since it needs to stringfy and parse huge data each time, it's too slow. I would like to go with React Redux. Am I right? Or any another suggestions?

Comment: While there's nothing stopping you from storing objects in your redux state, it is generally not recommended. Your redux state should also be serialized data. What aspect of "performance" are you specifically looking at? Cache would only really help with data fetches. Once you've fetched it and stored it in redux it is effectively cached (*in memory*) until the app reloads (*which is why we persist/initialize the state out to/from localStorage*). What are you wanting/needing to cache? Your question is a little too open/broad, please try to focus it more.

Comment: I think that react redux would be the better option but remember, this is not the goal how to use redux. Also, React has done a lot of work on their own context api (Redux uses that api) and it is now more recommended to use Context for most projects. https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html Also, you can implement a loading animation before the table has finished fetching the data. There are multiple npm packages that does this like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-async-table This might also do the job.

Comment: Redux is a state manager and you will lost data after each refresh or opening one page into new tab... you can persist data by using localStorage. In my opinion you shouldn't cache frequently update and fresh data! because you don't need to retrieve any old data in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are mainly worried about short term caching so that data is stored while the user moves around your SPA, I maintain a javascript library called [Gorgon JS](https://gorgonjs.dev) that I just put out a react useGorgon hook that makes it easy to cache API calls and specify a timeout for that cache.